# maven-release-plugin : exclude target directory for modifications

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm looking for a way to exclude the 'target' directory modifications during the maven release process. I tried below but it didn't work.

```
<configuration>
<checkModificationExcludes>
<checkModificationExclude>target</checkModificationExclude>
</checkModificationExcludes>
</configuration>
```

can any one help me please?

=============================
Update

```
<checkModificationExcludes>
<checkModificationExclude>${project.build.directory}</checkModificationExclude>
</checkModificationExcludes>
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: first of all, do you have a version history of the `target` directory? If yes, that's really bad.

Comment: Normally the `target` folder should not be added to the `SCM`, e.g. `svn:ignore` or `.gitignore`. Anyhow If you would like to exclude during the release, please try using the `${project.build.directory}` instead of `target`.

Comment: I think I'll have to say bad that I have the version of target directory. But in SCM it's empty directory, simply empty with no files at all. @CharleeChitsuk - how can I use this ${project.build.directory} and where. pls give can you give me some pointers?

Comment: Please try as your updated.

Comment: I have removed the target folder from SCM.